# Basic HATEOAS using angular - loading the entry point

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs, hateoas

I'm trying to do a clean implementation of a HATEOAS-style REST-api. My server side looks somewhat like this (in pseudo-HTTP and pseudo-JSON):

```
GET /api-entry-point
```

returns (with proper Content-Type and all that jazz):

```
{
  "_links": {
    "login": "/login",
    "users": "/someapi-part/users",
    "orders": "/other-part/orders"
  }
}
```

It is, therefore, the single point of entry for the application (the `_links` is in accordance with [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html)). A client of any kind would `GET /api-entry-point` and know where to find user or orders resources from there. A typical thing would be to login, then retrieve a list of users.

For my angular app, this means getting these links is the very first thing to do. I use a custom service (based on `$http`) that returns a promise to make HTTP-calls. This promise needs to resolve, once, at the application start. How do I ensure this happens using angular?

I've looked at the `resolve` attribute (on `$routeProvider`), but it seems tedious and silly to have every route depend on the resolve of `/api-entry-point`.

I've also checked [`module.run`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module) - but it does not resolve promises either.

How do I solve this? Is there a way or do I need a different approach/framework?

Comment: So your custom service replaces `$http` throughout your app?  I'm finding this a bit hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

> This promise needs to resolve, once, at the application start.

Maybe I didn't quite understand it but can't you just do the following?

In some controller on the first page of your app:

```
yourHttpService.getLinks('http://base-uri').then(links) {
   // do something with the links ...
}
```

At our project we have built a directive instead of a service. You pass in a uri and the directive exposes data, links, etc... on the scope so you can use it in your controllers or html ...